# semantical meaning of positions of letters in genomic sequences

Tags: genomes, data

here is a sequence from the [human_nontata_promoters.zip](https://pypi.org/project/genomic-benchmarks/) dataset that represents a genome.
My question is whether the position in this genome data is consequent. For example, the positional letters at 0 to 10 are in charge of "this" from the position from 10 to 14 for another property.

TCCTGCCTTTCCACTTGCACCAGTTTTCCCACCCCAGCCTCAGGGCGGGGCTGCCTCGTCACTTGTCTCGGGGCAGATCTGCCCTACACACGTTAGCGCCGCGCGCAAAGCAGCCCCGCAGCACCCAGGCGCCTCCTGGCGGCGCCGCGAAGGGGCGGGGCTGTCGGCTGCGCGTTGTGCGCTGTCCCAGGTTGGAAACCAGTGCCCCAGGCGGCGAGGAGAGCGGTGCCTTGCAGGGATGCTGCGGGCGG

My knowledge in biology is almost zero and I would like to use this dataset for some purposes, I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend thinking about DNA sequences more like words and sentences in a book than bits in a digital data file.

If you're reading a book and come across:

> The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog

you don't need to know what character # in the book the sentence started at to interpret it. If you have another edition of the same book and you read:

> The lazy brown fox jumps over the quick dog

you wouldn't say "oh, the 12th character used to be a 'w' but now it's an 'o'" (ignoring the spaces): that's true, but it's clear that the way these sequences *actually* differ is that two of the words got switched around. The rest of the sequence is the same, though, and much of the meaning is, too: there's still a fox jumping over a dog, even though about half of the characters are different if you compare the two strings letter-by-letter.

A [promoter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promoter_(genetics)) is like a word in this sequence, say "jumps"; a transcription factor will find places in the book with the word "jumps", and bind to that chunk of DNA. This will then influence transcription of the words that come after it.

In interpreting DNA sequences (or RNA, or protein) the solution to this general problem is called "[sequence alignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_alignment)", and sometimes it's fairly trivial and other times it's quite complex. There's a whole subfield of bioinformatics dedicated to these sorts of algorithms.

Comment: thanks a lot! Promoter seems to have some fixed semantical positions according to these -10 and -35 elements described in Wikipedia, isn't it?

Comment: @malocho Yes but remember these are all *relative* to something, not absolute positions.

Comment: ok, got it, thanks!